# Ошибка HTTP 500.19 — Internal Server Error на IIS 10.0

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, iis-10

При развертывании проекта WebAPI ASP.NET Core (.NET 8) возникает ошибка "Ошибка HTTP 500.19 — Internal Server Error (0x8007000d)".

[image: Ошибка HTTP 500.19 — Internal Server Error (0x8007000d)]

Для решения проблемы принимал следующие поптыки:

1. Переустановка всех необходимых служб IIS через включение и отключение компонентов Windows.[image: Включение и отключение компонентов Windows.]
2. Установка последней версии .NET 8 SDK, Runtime ASP.NET и Desktop.
   [image: .NET 8]
3. Дал полный доступ к папке с сайтом пользователю IIS_IUSER и другим.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Содержимое файла web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\FileApi.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 4afdcf34-32ad-447c-9120-151d723d6e1f-->
```

Подскажите, с чем еще может быть связано возникновение этой ошибки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мною было найдено решение проблемы. Чтобы избавиться от ошибки, мне нужно было дополнительно установить **Windows Hosting Bundle**. После его установки в списке модулей IIS появился **AspNetCoreModuleV2**.
[image: Список модулей приложения IIS]

Ссылка на актуальный установщик: [Установка Windows Hosting Bundle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/permalink/dotnetcore-current-windows-runtime-bundle-installer)
[image: Страница установки Windows Hosting Bundle]